# Calculate the complexity of a function in R

Tags: r, function, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need to calculate the complexity of a long function (600 lignes) with R.
My wanted result may look like this

```
start calculate complexity
**My function**
End calculate complexity
result= " the complexity of this function is x
```

I think that I miss understand but  What i found in benchmarking calculates just the runing time

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
*****function*****
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

and this function works just on vectors

```
    complexity(x, scaleMin, scaleMax, width = 7, measure = "complexity", 
   rescale = FALSE)
```

Is there another alternativ or I can update those functions to my need

Comment: I hope [ligne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne) is a typo and not some crazy new quality metric some consultant invented.

Comment: @candied_orange Sorry butI didn't undersand the use

Comment: "long function (600 lignes)"

Comment: lignes is likely "lines" in his language.

Comment: maybe https://cran.r-project.org/package=cyclocomp ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you have in mind by "complexity" you have many options, to name a few:

Cyclomatic complexity

- a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code - implemented for example by the cyclocomp package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cyclocomp/index.html

Memory use

- Base R offers an option to profile memory use (if R is compiled with R_MEMORY_PROFILING defined) using `Rprofmem` - a pure memory use profiler.
- Sampling memory profiling with `utils::Rprof(..., memory.profiling = TRUE)`
- profvis - A package extension of Rprof with very nice graphical output for both time elapsed and memory - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profvis/index.html

Time spent

- Time spent with many ways to measure, e.g. base function `system.time` returns the difference between two `proc.time` calls within which it evaluates an expression provided as argument. The simplest usage: `system.time(runif(10^8))`
- Time profiling packages such as https://cran.r-project.org/package=microbenchmark or https://cran.r-project.org/package=bench